# WebGL Perspective Projection Matrix issue with resizing canvas on both size

Tags: javascript, canvas, webgl

I have a WebGL viewer with perspective projection and it works fine when resizing the canvas height but nothing is happening when I resize canvas width.

Following is perspective projection matrix code

```
function getPerspectiveCamera(fovY, aspect, near,far)
{
  var PerspectiveProjectionMat = mat4.create();
  mat4.identity(PerspectiveProjectionMat);

  var D2R = Math.PI / 180.0;  
  var yScale = 1.0 / Math.tan(D2R * fovY / 2);
  var xScale = yScale / aspect;       
  var nearmfar = near - far;
  var m = [
    xScale, 0, 0, 0,
    0, yScale, 0, 0,
    0, 0, (far + near) / nearmfar, -1,
    0, 0, 2 * far * near / nearmfar, 0
  ];
  for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
     PerspectiveProjectionMat[i] = m[i];

  return PerspectiveProjectionMat;
}
```

I just modified the above code to make it work when the aspect ratio change.
But the model is not fitting properly when the canvas width is less than height (aspect ration less than 1)

Modified code is

```
function getPerspectiveCamera(fovY, aspect, near,far)
{
    var PerspectiveProjectionMat = mat4.create();
    mat4.identity(PerspectiveProjectionMat);        
    var D2R = Math.PI / 180.0;       
    if (aspect > 1) //canvas.width > canvas.height
    {
        var yScale = 1.0 / Math.tan(D2R * fovY / 2);
        var xScale = yScale / aspect;
    }
    else
    {
        var yScale = aspect / Math.tan(D2R * fovY / 2);
        var xScale = yScale / aspect;
        //var fovX = 2 * (Math.atan(Math.tan(utility.degToRad(34 * 0.5)) * aspect) * (180 / Math.PI));
        //var yScale = aspect / Math.tan(D2R * fovY / 2);
        //var xScale = 1.0;// yScale / aspect;           
    }


    var nearmfar = near - far;
    var m = [
        xScale, 0, 0, 0,
        0, yScale, 0, 0,
        0, 0, (far + near) / nearmfar, -1,
        0, 0, 2 * far * near / nearmfar, 0
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < m.length; i++)
        PerspectiveProjectionMat[i] = m[i];

    return PerspectiveProjectionMat;
}
```

Please explain to me that what is wrong here and give me your suggestion to fix it.

Added  pictures for your reference
[image: Model not fitted properly]
[image: Model fitted properly]

Comment: *"Please correct the above code so that the model fits properly when canvas width< height."* lol please ask for someone to explain what you're doing wrong instead of fixing your code for you.

Comment: @Rabbid76 - thanks for your reply, I tried your code but the reverse is happening.Model fits properly when change width but when I change height nothing is happening.I want the model to fit properly when change width or height.